# Delete selected item from a listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm able to delete items from database but only shows when I close the application and run it again.

```
def delete_command():
    backend.remove(selected[0])

def get_item(event):
    global selected
    index=lb.curselection()
    selected= lb.get(index)
    return selected

lb= Listbox(window)
lb.grid(row=4, column=0, rowspan= 5, columnspan=1)
lb.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", get_item)

b2 = Button(window, text="Delete", command=delete_command)
b2.grid(row=5, column=2)
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for the listbox? The method to delete items is documented.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have forgotten to delete item from Listbox.

```
def delete_command():
    backend.remove(selected[0])
    lb.delete(index)

def get_item(event):
    global selected,index
    index=lb.curselection()
    selected= lb.get(index)
    return selected

lb= Listbox(window)
lb.grid(row=4, column=0, rowspan= 5, columnspan=1)
lb.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", get_item)

b2 = Button(window, text="Delete", command=delete_command)
b2.grid(row=5, column=2)
```

I'm also so sorry to say, the quality of your code is pretty low. 
Do not define variables global unless it is really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For your case, you don't need to bind `<<ListboxSelect>>` in order to get the selected items.  Just get the selected items in `delete_command()`:

```
def delete_command():
    selected = lb.curselection()
    if selected:
        backend.remove(selected[0])
        lb.delete(selected)
```

In case you need to do something else when you select an item in the listbox, then you need to bind the event.